# Changing the behavior of autocomplete of labels in TexMaker

Tags: cross-referencing, overleaf, texmaker, auto-completion

As someone that is trying to migrate from Overleaf to another LaTeX editor, autocompleting labels in TexMaker has proven to be far from optimal to me. From what I found, I can make TexMaker autocomplete commands like \cref by inputting "\cref{#label#}" in customize completion, but that doesn't work as I would like it to.

In Overleaf, when I write \cref, it autocompletes it with \cref{}, and whenever I write anything in there that is in any segment of a label, such label is shown in the autocomplete options, while in TexMaker it only shows the labels that precisely start with that string of text, which makes it much harder to find some labels I made.

Another problem with TexMaker is that when I want to reference multiple labels, which I do by using, for example, \cref{label1,label2}, it won't offer any sort of autocompletion for the label after the comma.

So, is there a way to change the autocomplete feature of TexMaker to make it so that it behaves more like Overleaf's autocomplete with respect to the points I mentioned? Or is there another good LaTeX editor that has those features when autocompleting labels?

Comment: Welcome. // Why won't using the @ instead work for you? It will put a dot there which you can navigate by using the TAB-key. You can also do sth. like `\mycmnd{@}{@}` etc. Works fine for me right from the start.

Comment: Hello! What do you mean by using the @?

Comment: Try it and you‘ll see. Instead of putting ˋ#labelˋ put ˋ@ˋ … simple as that.